# Why do two experiment groups show opposite results when they are essentially the same?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model

My data contains three parameters, i.e., Treatment, Time, and Temperatures. I am looking into the effects of these three parameters and their interactions as I measure neuronal activity. The activity measures are neuronal phase (a relative timing of neuron's activity in a cycle period) and cycle frequency.

So far, I have tried GLMM and betareg models. GLMM didn't work on my data as it shows a "model convergence problem" warning.

When betareg was run, it did show the interactions. Although, I obtained an unusual result. For example: At 0 time, when the control and test data are essentially the same, I expect similar slopes. But the model shows not only different slopes but their signs are also opposite.

```
mod <- betareg(PDOFF ~ Treatment + Temperature + Time +
                         Treatment:Temperature + Treatment:Time +
                         Time:Temperature + 1 | Experiment,
                       data = PDOFF_Data)
```

- PD is a neuronal type, and PD OFF is a phase.*

[image]

And here is the PD OFF data showing that under both treatments, Control and Decentralized, at 0 Hr, it is essentially the same, yet the predictions showing that they differ.

[image]

Comment: It looks like there is an interaction between treatment and temperature.   Wasn't the point of the experiment it determine this?   You job as a researcher is now to ask why would there be an interaction?  It is unlikely you will find a "neuronal activity" expert at this forum to provide guidance.

Comment: Are you saying that there's an unexpected difference at baseline in a RCT? In that case, that would just be interpreted as "bad luck".

Comment: Thank you, Dave and Federico.

Comment: I have an idea why the interactions arise between treatment and temperature at 0.5, 6, and 24 HR. But that's not the point of my question. I would like a help in understanding that if PD OFF values under both treatments, Control and Decentralized, at 0 Hr, are essentially the same, and then why does the predictions showing that they differ. Please refer the data.